# MongoWaitQueueFullException when wait queue is still empty

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am using MongoDB C# driver version 2.17.0 in a prod service and found that the service faces a lot of MongoDB.Driver.MongoWaitQueueFullException every day. Initially I thought that the service was getting a lot of requests and it was hitting the wait queue limits. So, I started tracking connection count and wait queue size per service instance with [events](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver_core/events/).

Then I found that the service was well below the default active connection limit of 100 and the wait queue was empty most of the time too. But the exception was happening whenever there was a sharp rise in requests to open new connections to MongoDB. For example, 30 requests to open new connections in 10 seconds. I was able to re-produce this locally with k6 load testing tool. I made 100 requests gradually in 10 seconds and a small percentage (approx. 3% to 7%) of requests failed due to MongoWaitQueueFullException on multiple runs.

Is it possible to avoid this error since the service is not actually hitting the wait queue limits? One potential solution that comes to my mind is to open a minimum number of connections on startup so that my service always has some available connections to spare and can deal with sharp increase in requests more gracefully. Is there any other potential solution?

Comment: MongoWaitQueueFullException is the _local_ queue inside your application, if I remember correctly. I think it was something along the lines of there being too many threads waiting for a pooled connection. I can't 100% remember though since it is a _long time_ since I looked at it.

Comment: Isn't that error for when the queue is full? Because that is what I thought. But in my case, wait queue is not full. Moreover, as I am using async methods, shouldn't the driver use async methods too and not have thread waiting issue?